# How to bind property of level2 templated children from the level0 templated parent

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a Control template defined for my custom control say ControlA:

```
<Style TargetType="local:ControlA">
    <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ControlA">
                    <Grid>
                        <FlipView                              VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Canvas
                                                ZIndex="1"
                                                Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                                    BorderThickness="1">
                                                    <TextBlock Name="CurrentTimeMarkerTB"/> 
                                        </Canvas>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                        </FlipVIew>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

I want to bind the test property of CurrentTimeMarkerTB to some property of ControlA. I tried

```
Text="{Binding SomeDateTimePropertyOfControlA, 
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},  
       Converter={StaticResource TimelineFormatter},  
       ConverterParameter='0:hh:mm tt', TargetNullValue='CurrentTime'}"
```

But it never triggeres the converter's `TimelineFormatter` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no TemplatedParent in a DataTemplate, only in ControlTemplate. You need to retrieve the Parent using FindAncestor:

```
Text="{Binding SomeDateTimePropertyOfControlA, 
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ControlA}},  
       Converter={StaticResource TimelineFormatter},  
       ConverterParameter='0:hh:mm tt', TargetNullValue='CurrentTime'}"
```

If you can't use FindAncestor mode of RelativeSource you can use ElementName:

```
Text="{Binding SomeDateTimePropertyOfControlA, 
       ElementName=MyControlA,  
       Converter={StaticResource TimelineFormatter},  
       ConverterParameter='0:hh:mm tt', TargetNullValue='CurrentTime'}"
```

And then name your control:

```
<local:ControlA x:Name="MyControlA"/>
```

Comment: I gives a compile time error saying "The property 'AncestorType' was not found in type 'RelativeSource'."

Comment: @AshishAgrawal Are you using SilverLight and not WPF?

Comment: I am using wpf not silverlight. Actually my project is portable library. Targeted to Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: @AshishAgrawal I looked on google and it seems that it's either because: SilverLight or Windows Phone is used or because you use VS2008 (a visual studio bug). I tried the binding on my end on VS2013 and it works

Comment: I am using VS 2013. But I think it could be because, as I said, my project is a portable library and is targeted to both Windows 8.1 and WP 8.1 As you said, it does not work on WP it explains it I think. Is there any other workaround to this? I cant even use ElementName since I cant name my ControlA as its just a style and the actual instance.

Comment: @AshishAgrawal edited my answer, you can use ElementName but it's not a great solution